# Can I say that a scientific field has been "polymorphic" if it has changed dramatically over time?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

> The field of artificial intelligence, abbreviated as AI, has been
>   quite turbulent and **polymorphic** since its creation.

If not, what other word or construct could I use?

By *polymorphic* I meant that it had changed its subject and scope over time.

Comment: I wouldn't. I'd suggest: The study of artificial intelligence (AI) has been marked by controversial debate and widely differing theories from the start.

Comment: Could you use another word, like *multi-faceted*, instead?

Comment: You might consider a verb instead of an adjective: _The field of artificial intelligence, abbreviated as AI, has **evolved** since its creation._

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd be very wary of doing that, as polymorphism already has quite an established definition in the field of computer science. From [Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=polymorphism%20definition),

> **Polymorphism** *(Computing)*
>
> A feature of a programming language that allows routines to use variables of different types at different times.

Trying to apply a different defintion with a subfield is likely to cause readers confusion as to your intended meaning.

---

**Edit:** As an alternative, you could use 'in flux' or 'ever-changing':

- The field of artificial intelligence has been in a state of flux since its creation.
- The field of artificial intelligence has been ever-changing since its creation (as noted on [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/everchanging), this may imply continued future change is likely)

Comment: Thanks, but do you have some alternatives (see my edit)?

Answer (score 2):

I personally prefer **diversified**, in a sense of becoming diverse and varied, e.g.

> The field of artificial intelligence, abbreviated as AI, has been quite turbulent and **diversified** since its creation.

Comment: That kind of changes the meaning of what I said, please see my edit. But it might be even more suitable, so thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will be precisely what you want, but I think *"the field has been quite turbulent and kept reinventing itself since its creation"* sounds pretty close.

Comment: @ Damkerng T.: It's beginning to sound as if fields possess artificial intelligence.

Answer (score 2):

No, I wouldn't use *polymorphic*. It literally means "many forms," which doesn't convey much meaning here. Why not start with exactly what you mean: "The field of artificial intelligence (AI) has changed its subject and scope repeatedly since its creation"? That's a sentence you can build something interesting on.